# Google search results for my site include some strange urls - how to deal with them?

Tags: url, google

For some reason Google has indexed some pages on my Joomla website using strange urls starting https://www.pgweb.uk/?id=

https://www.pgweb.uk/?id=1605:new-dance-studio-launches-next-week

When clicked on, these always go to a page which looks similar to the home page but is missing some of its modules

As a consequence, they remain in Google's index, since it appears to the Google that these pages exist.

The correct url for this particular page should be

https://www.pgweb.uk/news/1605-new-dance-studio-launches-next-week

but this correct url isn't in Google's index.

When I try to remove individual incorrect urls, Google webmaster tools tells me they are not in the property.

I don't know how many of these incorrect urls are in Google's index.

Any idea of why this is happening and how to stop it?

Is there any way using the Redirects component that I can get 404 redirects for pages starting  so that they will eventually be removed from the Google index? The Redirects component has no effect with such urls when I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3 has a "**Modern Router**" option to **remove the article number** from the URL. You can enable the Modern Router in Joomla 3: In Content > Articles > Integration > URL Routing: Modern + Remove IDs from URLs: Yes.

**After enabling the Modern Router, the old URLs with numbers will result in 404 errors**.

You can use Joomla's **Redirects** to redirect wrong URLs to the right ones. If you have a lot of pages: Joomla's Redirects has an import function to import all `old-urls|new-urls`.